# Some redundant tags may need to be merged: [translation], [translate], [translating], and [translator]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

I have found 4 separate tags that appear to address exactly the same topic: [translator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/translator),  [translating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/translating), [translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/translate), and [translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/translation). Is it possible to merge all of these tags?

Eventually, I hope that each of these tags will be disambiguated into [machine-translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-translation) and [source-to-source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/source-to-source), which are about natural language translation and programming language translation, respectively.

Comment: Lost in [translation]?

Comment: [tag:language-translation]

Answer (score 8):

Clean-up is in progress.

[translator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/translator) <s>(x107)</s> - **Removed**

- Providing translations (human languages) => **Retag** to [localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localization)

  - References to Bing/Microsoft Translator => **Tag** with [microsoft-translator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-translator)
  - References to Google Translator => **Tag** with [google-translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-translate)
- Automatic translations (human languages) => **Retag** to [machine-translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-translation)
- Translating programming languages => **Retag** to [code-translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-translation)
- Translating data => **Retag** to [converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/converter)
- Everything else just had the tag removed (and other cleanup)

[translating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/translating) <s>(x12)</s> - **Removed**

- Providing translations (human languages) => **Retag** to [localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localization)
- Automatic translations (human languages) => **Retag** to [machine-translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-translation)
- Moving shapes => **Retag** to [transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transformation)
- Translating programming languages => **Retag** to [code-translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-translation)

[translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/translate) (x847) - Cleanup? - *To Do*

> To translate means to convert a program written in one language into a semantically equivalent program written in another, usually a lower lever, language.

- Moving shapes => **Retag** to [transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transformation)
- Automatic translations (human languages) => **Retag** to [machine-translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-translation)
- Translating programming languages => **Retag** to [code-translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-translation)

[translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/translation) (x2650) - Cleanup? - *To Do*

> Translation is the process of replacing strings in an application or website to make interfacing with the application or website easier for people from countries with different languages.

[i18n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/i18n) <s>(x42)</s> - This is now an alias of [internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internationalization)

Comment: What about [tag:language-translation]?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me something slightly different should be done.

[translator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/translator) should be burninated, IMO. The 116 current questions are about no one technology or platform.

[translating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/translating) I would think should go the same way as translator. It is used as a form of translate: [what would the word “is” mean in an algorithm in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340065/what-would-the-word-is-mean-in-an-algorithm-in-c), but also for topics like translate to Japanese.

[translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/translate) to me sounds like working with working with 2D/ 3D graphics. For example `myObject.Translate(x, y);` but it looks like the average question is actually referencing is the wiki definition:

> To translate means to convert a program written in one language into a
>   semantically equivalent program written in another, usually a lower
>   lever, language

This is what I would define as to [port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/port) or [port-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/port-code) but it looks like it has found a good home, regardless if the term is a little ambiguous on its own merit.

Finally, [translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/translation) and its wiki entry meet what I would define translation as :

> Translation is the process of replacing strings in an application or
>   website to make interfacing with the application or website easier for
>   people from countries with different languages.

But many of the questions refer to porting code, and not what the wiki suggests they should be about. I would say ideally this should be cleaned up.

In short:

- [translator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/translator) - burninate
- [translating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/translating) - Burninate
- [translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/translate) - Disambiguate and merge out questions to more concise terms
- [translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/translation) - Clean up the entries to meet the wiki definition.

Comment: No, I don't think it's a good idea to delete any of these tags. It would be much better to disambiguate them into [tag:source-to-source] and [tag:machine-translation].

Comment: Ideally I agree, but if each of [tag:translating]'s 16 question is disambiguated and moved elsewhere to be more accurate of the question, why not burninate or delete the tag?

Answer (score -1):

Someone's being overzealous.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373935/pascal-to-c-converter) had the "translator" tag removed (with no replacement added), even though it's clearly about language translation.

Comment: That is about porting or converting one language to another.  Different concept.  But you do make a good point that it needs [source-to-source] on it.

Comment: @JasonMArcher - I've always heard the concept referred to as "translation".  That and translating human languages are the two "legitimate" uses of the term, IMO.

Comment: In natural language yes, but we are talking about tags on StackOverflow, which should really have one meaning.