# Is your application [multilanguage] or just [multilingual]? Or are those actually synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

A while back I discovered [multilingual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multilingual), which appears to be dedicated to questions involving multiple natural languages. Unfortunately it also looks like [multilanguage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multilanguage) covers the same types of questions, just it doesn't have a tag wiki.

- [multilingual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multilingual) has 1187 questions and a tag wiki
- [multilanguage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multilanguage) has 686 questions and does not have a tag wiki

And there appears to be a serious overlap between the questions, though I cannot tell if that is intentional.

- [60 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multilanguage+locale+OR+multilanguage+localization+OR+multilanguage+translation) have [multilanguage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multilanguage) + another localization related tag
- [37 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multilanguage+multilingual) have both [multilingual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multilingual) and [multilanguage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multilanguage)

I cannot tell if [multilanguage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multilanguage) was supposed to fill the gap that [multilingual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multilingual) created with non-natural languages, but after looking at the first 50 questions I can say *most of them* (not all though) fit under [multilingual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multilingual).

**I propose that [multilanguage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multilanguage) is made a synonym of [multilingual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multilingual).**

Comment: For questions about providing translations of human languages, both tags should be burned in favor of [`localization`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localization) (including translations of human languages) and/or [`internationalization`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internationalization) (supporting variations in languages and cultures).  Related:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254608/some-redundant-tags-may-need-to-be-merged-translation-translate-translat

Comment: @JasonMArcher: The meanings of multiingual support/multilingualization and localization are completely different. Localization refers to adapting an application to the linguistic and cultural requirements of a particular locale. Multilingualization refers to enhancement to enable an application to deal with content in a multitude of languages independently of the application's/user's locale.

Comment: Good multilingual support (e.g. treating all text as some unicode form internaly, using font rendering systems that support opentype character-to-glyph mapping, etc.) is a good foundation for localization in applications, but there are plenty of applications that have been localized in legacy ways (locale-specific character encodings and fonts, etc.) that completely fail at multilingual support.

Comment: @R.. The industry standard term for that is [internationalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization).

Comment: @JasonMArcher: No. The terms localization, internationalization, and multilingualization are *all distinct*. Internationalization refers (roughly) to making it easy to swap out localizations (versus requiring major source-level changes for each localization). All applications using swappable message strings and swappable legacy 8-bit or DBCS CJK charsets were "internationalized" but had absolutely zero multilingual support.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  So there might be a few questions around that could use a NEW tag [multilingualization].  It was really hard to find anything talking about that term other than being a synonym.  http://sqa.fyicenter.com/FAQ/Testing-Techniques/What_are_Internationalization_Localization_Glo.html

Comment: Don't agree with the [tag:multilingual] tag wiki, someone has pasted it straight from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilingualism) which in terms of SO is completely out of context. There is a small section in that article [Multilingualism in computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilingualism#Multilingualism_in_computing) which points the reader back to [Internationalization and localization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) wiki entry which makes more sense.

Comment: Personally, both [tag:multilingual] and [tag:multilanguage] should both be synonyms of [tag:internationalization] I agree with @R comments but in basic terms [tag:internationalization] is the better fit.

Answer (score 13):

For some reason (and without the benefit of any research into the history of the associated tags), I instinctively associate *multilanguage* with synthetic languages (e.g. a "multilanguage software development environment") and *multilingual* with natural languages (e.g. a "multilingual learning environment").

But I see no way that any reasonable person can be expected to know with any certainty that any such distinction exists after simply reading the tag names.

And I suspect that it may simply not be worth the effort to design a set of tag names which precisely distinguish between all the possible variations of code written in one/multiple synthetic languages to display text written in one/multiple natural languages.

So the proposal to treat *multilanguage* and *multilingual* as synonyms strikes me as reasonable, even though I personally have different associations with the two terms.

Comment: If that is the case do we need a [tag:multilanguage] tag to tell us a question deals with multiple programming languages, why not just add the relevant programming language specific tags? When I think of [tag:multilanguage] or [tag:multilingual] they are just two ways of saying the same thing, the software has multiple language support or someone wants to bake in to their application multiple language support. Whether that is through internationalization or just providing localization for a small subset of languages it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Lankymart I'm not sure if you're agreeing with me agreeing with the proposal to treat the terms _mutilanguage_ and _multilingual_ as synonyms. As for you suggestion to add a specific tag for each relevant synthetic (programming) language, I don't disagree - but then why not do the same thing with natural (human) languages as well?

Comment: What are you on about synthetic language tags already exist? SO is a programming site after all. What did you think tags like [tag:c#], [tag:java], [tag:c++] and [tag:ruby] are for? My point was because they already exist  why would you need a [tag:multilanguage] tag?, it makes no sense. So taking that into consideration the [tag:multilanguage] tag has no place in that context, it just identifies that software has multi language support nothing more.

Comment: @Lankymart, I understand what programming (synthetic) and human (natural) languages are for. My point is that you *could* add specific tags for _French_, _Mandarin_, _Catalan_, etc. when describing a software localization issue just as you can add tags for _python_, _scheme_, _perl_, etc. when describing a library compatibility issue. And just as you might want to indicate that a particular issue concerns multiple unspecified natural languages (via tags _multilanguage_ or _multilingual_) you might also want to indicate that  an issue concerns multiple unspecified synthetic languages.

Comment: Glad we cleared that up. Not sure we need that level of detail on SO though.