# Should we remove [translate] (again)?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, blocklist-request

I saw [this request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254608/some-redundant-tags-may-need-to-be-merged-translation-translate-translat) two years ago to burninate the [translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/translate) tag.
However, it seems we currently have many different questions on this tag again, all about totally different purposes and subjects.

Isn't there a way to avoid re-creation of the same tags again and again?

Comment: Putting everything I'm doing on hold and thinking about a good pun.

Comment: The tag should probably be blacklisted, then.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: _"Lost in [translate]ion"_

Comment: *See you [translate]r*

Comment: @MarounMaroun: "Please translate [translate] to nothing"

Comment: @Roberrrt Transnever please instead of translater :(

Comment: @Roberrrt I would say See you [trans]later

Comment: Or a badly translated sentence, "We may burnate [translate] time another?" - Then watch all the suggested edits flow in >:]

Comment: @ThomasYates nit: there's no suggested edits to post on meta, only for tags wiki/excerpts.

Answer (score 5):

> Isn't there a way to avoid re-creation of the same tags again and again?

There is. See the [blacklist-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/blacklist-request/info) tag info:

> This tag is used in requests for adding one or more tags to the
>   blacklist, preventing them from ever being used again. For other
>   questions about the tag blacklist, use [tag-blacklist].
>   **Blacklisting a tag prevents anyone from ever using that tag on a new
>   question or editing a question without removing it**.

Cerbrus already [edited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/339091/2) your post and added the tag for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, the tag should be burninated.

For what it's worth, that tag was NOT burninated before. The linked question is a retag request and proposes all these tags to be merged. In my opinion, this is a burninate request rather than a blacklist request.

The tag description states that:

> To translate means to convert a program written in one language into a semantically equivalent program written in another, usually a lower level, language.

...which means that the tag was created for code translation requests. However, **[code translation requests are too broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296119)** which means that the whole tag should be removed.

Now, the problem is that the tag has multiple meanings. Some people confuse it and use it when they have a string `translate`. Others for Google Translate issues, others to translate some text from one language to another, etc., etc.

Summarising:

> 1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? Is it unambiguous?**

No. As mentioned, it has multiple meanings. The tag description shows that most questions are off-topic, but since some people don't even bother to read it, they just post questions about Google Translate, text translation, etc.

> 2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

The concept described is not on-topic, it's too broad as has been mentioned. The other uses of it *may* be on-topic, but if the tag was used to tag everything about translation, then it would be **too ambiguous**.

> 3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

No. It just confuses further the reader and/or future answerers. They'll just have to think what kind of translation this post is about.

> 4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No, no and no. For hundredth time, **no**. Does it mean code translation? Text translation? Image translation? The tag is too, too ambiguous.

In other words:

## Let it burn!